# Test phone numbers in different countries

Tags: sms, twilio, phone-number, twilio-api

Does twilio provide any test mobile numbers for different countries. I want to test whether SMS is sending successfully to some mobile number in Canada.

Is there any test mobile numbers that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: You can buy from Twilio mobile numbers in Canada.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not have test numbers available for you to send messages to. However, you can instrument your code such that you can find out from Twilio when you [send messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) that they are being delivered.

I recommend you set the [`StatusCallback` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional) when you send messages. You set it to a URL on your server that can receive incoming webhooks and it will receive a request each time your message status changes to one of the following: queued, failed, sent, delivered, or undelivered.

That way you can be sure that your messages are sending correctly and arriving at the phones you expect them to.

Let me know if that helps at all.